# How to import csv with multi level column index

Tags: python, pandas, import, multi-index, yfinance

When I import more than one stock in yahoo finance I get a multindex. I'm trying to export as an csv file and them import the same dataset with the same indexes. I tried to use `index = False` in `.to_csv` method but it drops the row index, which is something that I don't want.

Basically I can't find a way to make `stocks_sample_csv` have the same index as `stocks_sample`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
import yfinance as yf

list_symbols = ["CERS", "CERU", "CETV", "CEVA", "CFA", "CFBK",
                "CFFI", "CFFN", "CFGE", "CFNB", "CFNL", "CFO",
                "CFRX", "CFRXW", "CFRXZ", "CG", "CGEN", "CGIX",
                "CGNX", "CGO", "CHCI", "CHCO", "CHDN", "CHEF",
                "CHEV", "CHFC", "CHFN", "CHI", "CHKE", "CHKP", 
                "CHLN", "CHMG", "CHNR", "CHOP", "CHRS", "CHRW",
                "CHSCM", "CHSCN", "CHSCO", "CHSCP"]
start = date(2017, 10, 1)
end = date(2020, 6, 25)

stocks_sample = yf.download(list_symbols, start, end, group_by='ticker')

#for checking 
print(stocks_sample)
stocks_sample.columns.levels[0]
stocks_sample.columns.levels[1]

stocks_sample.to_csv('stocks_sample.csv')
stocks_sample_csv = pd.read_csv('stocks_sample.csv')

#now check the imported .csv file
print(stocks_sample_csv)
stocks_sample_csv.columns.levels[0]
stocks_sample_csv.columns.levels[1]
```

By the way, I'm doing this so I don't need to donwload everytime I open my python console.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following changes-

```
stocks_sample = stocks_sample.reset_index() #will create the multi index as separate columns
stocks_sample.to_csv('stocks_sample.csv')

#while importing 
stocks_sample_csv = pd.read_csv('stocks_sample.csv')
stocks_sample_csv.set_index(['index0', 'index1']) #change the list to the list of columns which contain the previous indexes.
```

Comment: You can change the ```['index0', 'index1']``` to the list of columns that were created from the ```reset_index()``` to get back your multi-indices

Comment: I get a 'lenght mismatch'. Can you show in the answer?